# Undefined variable error when using sass @use in vite (@import is OK)

Tags: sass, vuejs3, vite, dart-sass

I got an `Undefined variable` error when i use [sass @use](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use)  in vite

demo is here [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/Mr-Nobody-li/vite-demo/master?file=%2Findex.html&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A25%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A10%2C%22startColumn%22%3A25%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A10%7D%5D&workspace=%257B%2522activeFileId%2522%253A%2522clck6o50l00077neo8h494lgz%2522%252C%2522openFiles%2522%253A%255B%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%255D%252C%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522gitSidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522COMMIT%2522%252C%2522spaces%2522%253A%257B%2522clck6o7x3000x356hlodlc529%2522%253A%257B%2522key%2522%253A%2522clck6o7x3000x356hlodlc529%2522%252C%2522name%2522%253A%2522Default%2522%252C%2522devtools%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522key%2522%253A%2522clck6o7x3000y356hubve304k%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PROJECT_SETUP%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PREVIEW%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522clck6o9vj007w356h22e477d3%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522clck6o86b003g356hrif80mi8%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522currentSpace%2522%253A%2522clck6o7x3000x356hlodlc529%2522%252C%2522spacesOrder%2522%253A%255B%2522clck6o7x3000x356hlodlc529%2522%255D%257D)

I don't know what's wrong with my configuration for sass

Answer (score 1):

You need to use @forward instead of @use to re-export variables.
src/styles/index.scss

```
- @use "./var.scss";
+ @forward "./var.scss";
```